# WEBスクレイピングができない

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping

PythonでWEBページをスクレイピングし、あるサイトから店名と住所情報を取得したいと考えています。
コラボラトリー環境で以下のコードを試してみたのですが、情報を取得できません。
コードのどこがいけないのかスクレイピングに詳しい方教えていただけませんでしょうか？

```
!pip install geocoder
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from google.colab import files
import os
import geocoder
from time import sleep
from google.colab import files

url1 = "https://www.aeon.com/store/list/%E7%B7%8F%E5%90%88%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC/%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB/p_"
url2 = "/?q=aeoncom"
cols = ['store_name','address','latlon']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[],columns=cols)

for i in range(1,22):
  response = requests.get(url1 + str(i) + url2).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

  for tag in soup.find_all('div', class_="storeInfo"):
    atag_stname = tag.find('a', class_="storeName")
    atag_adname = tag.find('span', class_="address")
    latlon = geocoder.arcgis(atag_adname)

    record = pd.Series([atag_stname.text,atag_adname.text,latlon.latlng],index=df.columns)
    df = df.append(record,ignore_index=True)
    sleep(2)
df.to_csv("df_ion.csv")
files.download('df_ion.csv')
```

Comment: 単に「取得できない」だけだとどんな問題があったのか回答者には分からないので、具体的にどのような問題が起こったのか [edit] して追記いただけませんでしょうか。たとえば○○というエラーが出たとか、エラーは出なかったけど意図していた結果と違い○○が出力されたとか、そういったことです。

Comment: `q=aeoncom` とは何でしょう。付けてる意味教えてください

Comment: コラボラトリー環境では無いですが、`requests.get(url1 + str(i) + url2)`が終了していないような感じですね。そこで指定されたURLをブラウザに指定すると取得して表示されるので、おそらくJavaScriptを実行できる環境が必要です。Googleのようにスクレイピングを感知してブラウザからとは違う内容を返すとか、そもそも応答しないとかはやっていないでしょう。コラボラトリーで使いたいならPhantomJSとかでしょうか？ あるいはブラウザ上での動作を調べて、JavaScriptの動作に相当する依頼を`requests.get()`で行うようにすれば良いと思われます。

Comment: ところで、`sleep(2)` のインデントはそれでよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: 当初の問題が解決した後で別の問題が出た場合には、追記してしまうのではなく **新しい質問** として投稿してください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User-Agent` を設定すると期待通りに動作する様です。

```py
headers = {
  'User-Agent':
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100'
}
              :

for i in range(1,22):
  response = requests.get(url1 + str(i) + url2, headers=headers).text
              :

print(df)

   store_name               address                                    latlon
0    イオン札幌麻生店    北海道札幌市北区北39条西4-1-5    [43.10729026007806, 141.3397210097591]
1    イオン札幌琴似店     北海道札幌市西区琴似2条4-2-2   [43.07673248139989, 141.30288212620786]
              :
```